# Apache/httpd 'Header set Server' is ignored/overridden

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I am using this in a `VirtualHost`

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    Header set ProcessingTime "%D"
    Header set Server "Apache 2.4"
</IfModule>
```

I can see that the `ProcessingTime` is set happily, but `Server` is set by some default, which tells too much about software versions of the server.

What am I doing wrong and can I figure, where the header `Server` is finally set?

I have tried:

- `sudo grep -Rin "Header" /etc/httpd/conf.d/` -> no result for `Header set Server`
- `sudo grep -Rin "servertokens" /etc/httpd/conf.d/` -> absolutely no result

Apache version: *Apache/2.4.53 (codeit)* on CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ServerTokens` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens) in the server config context, instead.

> `ServerTokens Full` (or not specified)
> Server sends (e.g.): `Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Unix) PHP/4.2.2 MyMod/1.2`
>
> `ServerTokens Prod[uctOnly]`
> Server sends (e.g.): `Server: Apache`
>
> `ServerTokens Major`
> Server sends (e.g.): `Server: Apache/2`
>
> `ServerTokens Minor`
> Server sends (e.g.): `Server: Apache/2.4`
>
> `ServerTokens Min[imal]`
> Server sends (e.g.): `Server: Apache/2.4.2`
>
> `ServerTokens OS`
> Server sends (e.g.): `Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Unix)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually people want to [hide the Server](https://tecadmin.net/hide-apache-version-from-http-header/) header because some auditor told them to or their vulnerability scanner doesn't understand backporting.

Have a look for ServerTokens in your config and [the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens).